# Cannot execute apache2 restart command in ubuntu21.10

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, localhost, apache2

After I executed the command: `sudo systemctl restart apache2` in the terminal, it prompted an error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" for details.
```

After executing the `systemctl status apache2.service` command according to the above prompt, I received this prompt:

```
 × apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor prese>
         Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-20 09:50:13 +06; 9min>
           Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
        Process: 14920 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/F>
            CPU: 18ms
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: [Mon Dec 20 09:50:13.739503 2021] [alias:>
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably dete>
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make>
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make>
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: no listening sockets available, shutting >
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14920]: Action 'start' failed.
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14920]: The Apache error log may have more inform>
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

After executing the `journalctl -xeu apache2.service` command according to the above prompt, I received this prompt:

```
The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: [Mon Dec 20 09:50:13.739503 2021] [alias:>
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably dete>
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make>
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make>
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: no listening sockets available, shutting >
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14923]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit apache2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-co>
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14920]: Action 'start' failed.
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT apachectl[14920]: The Apache error log may have more inform>
Жел 20 09:50:13 RTT systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3993 and the job result is failed.
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the last few lines from `/var/log/apache2/error.log`? This will contain more specific information about why Apache will not run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its possible that you may already have some other webserver running on your website which is using port 80, because you have error `RTT apachectl[14923]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make>`

Please try this:

Check first what is using port 80

`sudo netstat -nap | grep 80`

Now use command to identify process (in my case "httpd")

`ps -ax | grep httpd`

If you identify the process please kill them and try again to restart apache2.

Comment: There is no such command: `sudo: netstat: command not found`

Comment: Please install with command --> `sudo apt-get install net-tools`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and have solved it this way:

1. see what is using port 80. Get the PID from the results.

   sudo lsof -i :80
2. Kill the process.

   sudo kill [PID]
3. Reboot the system.

   sudo reboot

Now it is done for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have program running on port 80. run this.

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

you should see the listed process with its PID
you can either kill the program(s) or reconfigure apche2 to run on different port, However, i recommend killing it since reconfiguring might be tedious. run the following command.
#replace PID with the actuall PID number of the program

```
sudo kill PID
```

now you can restart your machine and just proceed. You should be fine.

```
sudo reboot
```